# Why is Internet Explorer version dependent on the OS?

Tags: internet-explorer

Why are XP users stuck with IE8? It seems like such a weird tight-coupling. Almost all other applications seem to work perfectly fine with XP, Vista, 7 and 8. I don't really see why this specifically would need such a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

**Because that's a choice Microsoft has made.**

Really. It's as simple as that. **They have coupled the web browser very tightly to the operating system,** and thus replacing it means replacing large chunks of the OS. Even if the differences themselves were to be relatively small, *it'd still be differences* and those need to be supported (coded, debugged, documented, tested, maintained, ...).

Note that this isn't even the same problem as removing the browser entirely; it's highly likely that for the type of integration done between Windows and MSIE, the APIs are quite different between versions of MSIE.

And of course, [extended support for Windows XP non-Embedded ended in April 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?alpha=Windows+XP). So by now they have even less of a reason to support anything Windows XP.